# Hibernate Search : The field () used for the spatial query is not configured as spatial field

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-spatial

I have the classes Organization and Coordinates.
Coordinates is as follow :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COORDINATES")
@Indexed
@Spatial
public class Coordinates implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Coordinates() {}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "COORDINATES_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
private Long id;

@Field
@Latitude
@Column(name = "LATITUDE", nullable = false)
private Double latitude;

@Field
@Longitude
@Column(name = "LONGITUDE", nullable = false)
private Double longitude;
```

I put the annotation @IndexedEmbedded in the coordinates field in the Organization (which is @Indexed + @Entity + @Table).
How come the spatial feature is not recognized in my query ? I have the following exception :

> org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000131: The
>   field 'organization.Organization#coordinates' used for the spatial
>   query is not configured as spatial field. Check the proper use of
>   @Spatial respectively SpatialFieldBridge at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedSpatialQueryBuilder.createSpatialQuery(ConnectedSpatialQueryBuilder.java:63)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedSpatialQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedSpatialQueryBuilder.java:38)

---

### Edit 1

I tried adding a name to the Spatial annotation but I got the error saying @Latitude and @Longitude couldn't be found.
So I tried implementing Hibernate's Coordinates, changing @Entity to @Embeddable, changing @IndexedEmbedded for @Spatial in Organization class on the 
`coordinates` attribute, removing @Latitude + @Longitude in my Coordinates class, overriding `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()`. Now I have the following exception :

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   com.(...).model.organization.Organization.coordinates
>   references an unknown entity:
>   com.(...).model.localization.Coordinates

I am using :

- hibernate-core : 5.2.12.Final
- hibernate-jpamodelgen : 5.2.12.Final
- hibernate-search-orm : 5.8.2.Final
- hibernate-search-elasticsearch : 5.8.2.Final

I talked with the other devs and it seems like they need features that changed in the more recent versions so we don't want to change for the moment.

Here is the interesting part in Organization class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "CODE" }) })
@Indexed
public class Organization implements Serializable, FileEntity {
    // lots of attributes, getters, setters, constructor
    @Spatial(name = "location", spatialMode = SpatialMode.RANGE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COORDINATES_ID")
    private Coordinates coordinates;
}
```

And the modified Coordinates class :

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "COORDINATES")
@Indexed
public class Coordinates implements org.hibernate.search.spatial.Coordinates, Serializable {
    // serial, constructor, id get+set
    @Field
    @Column(name = "LATITUDE", nullable = false)
    private Double latitude;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE", nullable = false)
    private Double longitude;
    @Override
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 2

I added the "(of = "location")" in @Latitude and @Longitude.
I still have the error :

> Error message:
>   {"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to
>   find geo_point field [coordinates.location]" (...)

Maybe it comes from the query ?
Query :

```
final BooleanJunction bool = queryBuilder.bool().must(queryBuilder.bool()                                                              
    .should(...)
    .should(...)
    .should(queryBuilder
        .spatial()
        .onField("coordinates.location")
        .within(12, Unit.KM)
        .ofLatitude(form.getLatitude())
        .andLongitude(form.getLongitude())
        .createQuery())
    .createQuery())
    .must(...)
    .must(...)
    .must(...);
final FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(bool.createQuery(), Organization.class);
fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(form.getMaximumNumberOfResult());
fullTextQuery.setProjection(FullTextQuery.SPATIAL_DISTANCE, FullTextQuery.THIS);
fullTextQuery.setSpatialParameters(form.getLatitude(), form.getLongitude(), "coordinates.location");
fullTextQuery.setProjection(FullTextQuery.THIS, FullTextQuery.SCORE);
```

The field "coordinates" in Organization is @IndexedEmbedded and the Coordinates class is as you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

So, first, it's a bit odd that Hibernate Search managed to start up to begin with, because your mapping contains a mistake: you should set the `name` attribute on the `@Spatial` annotation. Then Hibernate Search will create a field in the `Coordinates` type with that name (let's say "location").
Once that is done, you will be able to query that field from the `Organization` type using the `coordinates.location` name.

I know, it sounds a bit silly in this case, but generally the entity you put the `@Spatial` annotation on is a business type, not something representing coordinates, so it makes more sense.

Another option would be to turn your `Coordinates` type into an embeddable instead of an entity, make it implement `org.hibernate.search.spatial.Coordinates`, and put the `@Spatial` annotation on the `Organization#coordinates` property instead of putting it on the `Coordinates` type. Then you wouldn't need the `@IndexedEmbedded` anymore nor the `@Latitude`/`@Longitude`, and you could actually just use the `coordinates` field name when querying.

If the above doesn't work, please add the versions of Hibernate Search and Hibernate ORM you are using, and the code of the `Organization` class.

---

**EDIT**: In answer to your edit...

About the `@Latitude`/`@Longitude` annotations not being found: you need to use the `of` attribute of these annotations to match the name of your field.

If you *do not* switch to `@Embeddable`, this would lead to something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COORDINATES")
@Indexed
@Spatial(name = "location")
public class Coordinates implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Coordinates() {}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "COORDINATES_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
private Long id;

@Field
@Latitude(of = "location")
@Column(name = "LATITUDE", nullable = false)
private Double latitude;

@Field
@Longitude(of = "location")
@Column(name = "LONGITUDE", nullable = false)
private Double longitude;

}
```

About your "org.hibernate.AnnotationException" after switching to an embeddable: you need to remove the `@ManyToOne` on the `coordinates` attribute and replace it with `@Embedded`. Embedded attributes are very different from associations, please have a look at the [Hibernate ORM documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I edited my question to answer yours, as it doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: @Marie I added solutions to the problems mentions in your edit.

Comment: Edited again. I have no clue why it's not working. Thank you for helping me btw.

Comment: @Marie I see you're using the Elasticsearch integration. You should re-generate the Elasticsearch schema whenever you change your Hibernate Search mapping, otherwise Elasticsearch won't work correctly. See ["schema management strategies" in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.8/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-schema-management-strategy) While developing, I would recommend `drop-and-create`, especially if you can easily reindex all of your data on startup.

Comment: Yes, we are using the drop-and-create